# Evolution strategy with individual stepsizes

Tags: matlab, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm trying to find a good solution with an evolution strategy for a 30 dimensional minimization problem. Now I have developed with success a simple (1,1) ES and also a self-adaptive (1,lambda) ES with one step size.

The next step is to create a (1,lambda) ES with individual stepsizes per dimension. The problem is that my MATLAB code doesn't work yet. I'm testing on the sphere objective function:

```
function f = sphere(x)
    f = sum(x.^2);
end
```

The plotted results of the ES with one step size vs. the one with individual stepsizes:

[image: results]

The blue line is the performance of the ES with individual step sizes and the red one is for the ES with one step size.

The code for the (1,lambda) ES with multiple stepsizes:

```
% Strategy parameters
tau = 1 / sqrt(2 * sqrt(N));
tau_prime = 1 / sqrt(2 * N);
lambda = 10;

% Initialize
xp = (ub - lb) .* rand(N, 1) + lb;
sigmap = (ub - lb) / (3 * sqrt(N));
fp = feval(fitnessfct, xp');
evalcount = 1;

% Evolution cycle
while evalcount <= stopeval

    % Generate offsprings and evaluate
    for i = 1 : lambda
        rand_scalar = randn();

        for j = 1 : N
            Osigma(j,i) = sigmap(j) .* exp(tau_prime * rand_scalar + tau * randn());
        end

        O(:,i) = xp + Osigma(:,i) .* rand(N,1);
        fo(i) = feval(fitnessfct, O(:,i)');
    end

    evalcount = evalcount + lambda;

    % Select best
    [~, sortindex] = sort(fo);
    xp = O(:,sortindex(1));
    fp = fo(sortindex(1));
    sigmap = Osigma(:,sortindex(1));
end
```

Does anybody see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your mutations have a bias: they can only ever increase the parameters, never decrease them. sigmap is a vector of (scaled) upper minus lower bounds: all positive. exp(...) is always positive. Therefore the elements of Osigma are always positive. Then your change is Osigma .* rand(N,1), and rand(N,1) is also always positive.

Did you perhaps mean to use randn(N,1) instead of rand(N,1)? With that single-character change, I find that your code optimizes rather than pessimizing :-).